# Selenium Webdriver - How to avoid data duplication

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Suppose I have normal "Add Users" module that I want to automate using Java scripting, how I can avoid data duplication to avoid error message such as "User already exist"?

Comment: Use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html This comes packaged with `selenium-java`.

Comment: clean the data in a teardown step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways in which this can be automated. You are receiving ***'User already exists'*** due to fact that you're (probably) running your `'Add Users'` test cases using ***static*** variables.

**Note:** For the following examples I will consider a basic ***registration*** flow/scenario of a new user: `name`, `email`, `password` being the required fields. 
**Note-002:** My language of choice will be JavaScript. You should be able to reproduce the concept with Java with ease.

**1.)** Pre-pending/Post-pending a ***unique*** identifier to the information you're submitting (e.g.: `Date()` returns the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 => it will always be unique when running your test case)

```
var timestamp = Number(new Date());
var email = 'test.e2e' + timestamp + '@<yourMainDomainHere>'
```

**Note:** Usually, the `name` & `password` don't need to be unique, so you can actually use hardcoaded values without any issues.

**2.)** The same thing can also be achieved using the `Math.random()` (for JS), which returns a value between 0 and 1 (`0.8018194703223693`), 18 digits long.

```
var almostUnique = Math.random();
// You can go ahead and gen only the decimals
almostUnique = almostUnique.toString().split('.')[1];
var email = 'test.e2e' + almostUnique + '@<yourMainDomainHere>'
```

**!!!** Warning: While `Math.random()` is not actually ***unique***, in hundreds of regression runs of 200 functional test cases, I didn't have the chance of seeing a duplicate.

**3.)** (Not so elegant | Harder exponentially harder to implement) If you have access to your web-apps **backend API** and through it you can execute different actions in the DB, then you can actually write yourself some scripts that will run after your ***registration*** test cases, like a **cleanup** suite.

These scripts will have to remove the previously added user from your database.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what language you are coding in, but use whatever language you use's random function to generate random numbers and/or text for the user id.  It won't guarantee that there will not be a duplicate, but the nature of testing is such that you should be able to handle both situations anyway.  If this is not clear or I don't understand your question correctly, you'll need to provide a lot more information: what you've tried, what language you use, etc.