# Jmeter Variables Random in User and Email

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, automated-tests

I need to do some performance testing and simulate **100 different users**, but how do I make random variables for the user and e-mail?

[image]

Comment: I don't know `JMeter`, but the logic you are looking for should be the same as in **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074535/selenium-webdriver-how-to-avoid-data-duplication/44076182#44076182)** response to a similar question here on Stack. Basically, you need to leverage concatenating your `baseUsername`/`baseEmail` with a random parameter. Hope you solve the issue. Cheers!

Comment: Use counters and random variables , CSV config in Jmeter. Other ways are also possible

Answer (score 7):

You can use [__RandomString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) to generate a random email, something like:

```
${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}@hotmail.com

the above function will return a random alphabetic string 10 characters long
```

Demo:

[image: RandomStringDemo]

You can put __RandomString() function directly into [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) parameters like:

[image: Random String parameteres]

The __RandomString() function calls will be substituted by generated random values in the runtime each time the functions are called.

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) guide to get started with Functions in JMeter tests